# Initializing and using a tf.placeholder(tf.string), feeding a value to it and converting it back to a string when necessary

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am having trouble implementing a model in tensorflow.
I want to program a model that predicts the polarity of a sentiment. To do this I first have to train the model. This is where an error occurs.

I use three variables: sentence (or sentiment), target (the word in the sentence on which the polarity applies) and the polarity itself. The first two variables are strings and the polarity is a vector ([1,0,0] when positive, [0,0,1] when negative).

To make these variables I use tf.placeholder(tf.string). When I run the model I get the following error: "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype string"

I also think I have an issue when I want to do operations on the sentence variable: I need to split the sentence in its words, but since sentence is a placeholder, I first have to convert it back to a string.

The input of the model are three vectors: sVec (a vector of all sentences as strings), tVec (a vector of all targets as strings) and pVec (a vector of all polarities as vectors)

I have been dealing with this error for quite some time now, so any help is appreciated. Below you find the code. Thanks in advance.

```
polarity = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, c_cardi])#label
sentence = tf.placeholder(tf.string)  #inputdata
target = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

def multilayer_perceptron(mi, target, weights, biases):
    # This method works correctly


def modelA(sentence, target):
    # The error might refer to this:
    sess2 = tf.Session()
    sentence = sess2.run(sentence) # I need to get the value of the tensor here
    sess2.close()
    words = sentence.split()
    # Code goes on, no error here
    return prediction


def trainModelA(sVec, tVec, pVec):
    prediction = modelA(sentence, target)
    cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=polarity))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost_function)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # The error might refer to this part
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={sentence:sVec, target: tVec, polarity:pVec})
            # Code goes on

trainModelA(sVec, tVec, pVec)
```

EDIT:

It seems to me that the error occurs at the line: sentence = sess2.run(sentence). Because I run modelA(sentence, target), I have sentence as an input but this has not yet been filled with a value. However, this seemed the way to go so I still don't not what is going on.

Comment: It would help if you'd update your code so that others can reproduce your error.

Comment: @MatthewScarpino, thank you for your comment, but this might be hard since the data that I use is very large (a document with all word embeddings)

Comment: You don't have to provide all of your code or all of your data. Just enough so that others can reproduce the error.